# Can't add JLabel to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have this code:

```
  ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8384/8682624224_4e44bf947d_h.jpg"); 
  subStream.add(new JLabel(ii));
```

It's meant to add `JLabel` with photo to `JPanel` called `subStream`.
But it doesn't work, no errors or anything. Why so?

[image]

Image is supposed to appear in 3rd JPanel, just above Buttons.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: did you check your console for an error/stack trace?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: There is no errors thrown.

Comment: I've added screenshot

Comment: @arleitiss, A screenshot doesn't help. The problem is with your code.

Comment: You do realise that you source image is `1600x1068` in size...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things to be aware of...

- `ImageIcon` can fail silently...annoying I know...this is because...
- `ImageIcon` uses a background thread to load the images, this is because it was designed to allow for slow sources (dial up networks) which might need time to fully realise the image.

You should use `ImageIO.read` to test the `URL` to discount potential issues with downloading the image.  This will throw an `IOException` if the image can't be loaded for some reason and will block until the image is fully loaded, so beware of that

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

For example...

[image: Downloaded Image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8384/8682624224_4e44bf947d_h.jpg"));
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(label);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

So, this discounts the image and web server as the potential problem (at least from within my network), there must be something else wrong with your code.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Well, I just tried another photo from my Flickr photos, but I retrieved it's thumbnail:
https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8392/8681511947_c2a72544d2_t.jpg

But it still doesn't show up, in fact - I tried adding just JLabel("Hello"); to JPanel and it still doesn't add. 
The login behind this behavior seems weird.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Not sure if you mean what I understood, but anyway:
I created new project, copied same layout of that page, added same code, and it's still same. How can I upload that barebone project I just created to show?

Comment: what do you mean by discount the image?

Comment: @KickButtowski Is loading the image the problem or is it something else the problem

Comment: Am I allowed to post links to files I uploaded?

Comment: No, post the code into the question itself, people don't links to external sites...Just like I did in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking ImageIcon(String filename) constructor. Try with the URL one:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("your URL"));

// Imports
// ...

public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MyFrame()
    {
        super("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/0/0b/Vegeta_-_Sigla_Iniziale_Dragon_Ball_Kai.jpg");

            getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url)));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it wasn't created with code, it was drag'n'drop in netbeans

Comment: I've tried creating a JFrame with a JLabel inside it's content pane and it works perfectly.

Comment: *"..and it works perfectly."*   For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).   Of failing code, of course.  It will possibly begin to fail after adding a single other component.

Comment: Nice edit.  But then, you had my (up) vote the moment you wrote *"You are invoking ImageIcon(String filename) constructor."* :)  Hopefully it will prompt the OP to post an MCVE that *fails.*

Comment: Ooh.. I just realized I mistook you for the OP when you wrote *"it works perfectly"*  Silly me!